# Divergence of an improper integral involving periodic function

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, periodic-functions

Say we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is periodic, non-negative, continuous, and not identically zero. I have to prove that the improper integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{x}}dx$ diverges.

I tried using integration by parts ($f$ is continuous so it has an anti-derivative) and then determining convergence/divergence separately  ($\int_{1}^{\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{x}}dx$ = $\lim_{b\to\infty}(\frac{F(b)}{b}-F(1)+\int_{1}^{b}{\frac{F(x)}{x^2}}dx)$, but I can't seem to find what to do from here. Am I on the right track or am I missing something?

Comment: By $fx$ do you mean $f(x)$, or $x \cdot f(x)$?  And I presume you want to exclude $f=0$.

Comment: Robert Israel is right. We don't want $f$ to be $0$. And if that's the case, you can prove that there are infinitely many sets with measure $\geq c$ for some $c>0$ on which $f$ does not vanish.

Comment: Yes I'm excluding f=0 and I mean f(x). I edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG $f$ is periodic with period $1$. Since $f$ is non-negative, not identically zero, and continuous, there is an interval $I$ of length $\delta>0$ in $(1,2)$ on which $f(x)>0$. This implies $\int_{I} f(x)\,dx = k>0$. Then
$$
\int _1^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{f(x)}{x}{dx} \geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} \int_{1}^{2}f(x){dx} 
$$
$$
\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} \int_{I}f(x){dx}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{n}  = \infty
$$So the integral diverges. If $f$ is continuous and periodic with period $1$, a necessary and sufficient condition that $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx$ converge is that $\int_1^2 f(x)\,dx = 0$.

Comment: f is non-negative, not positive meaning m might as well be 0, so this argument doesn't apply here.

Comment: @GalBenAyun you stated $f$ nonzero. You can actually modify this argument: if $f$ is (non-negative) not identically zero and continuous, it is strictly positive on an interval of length $\delta>0$. By a similar argument, integrating over these integrals is enough to show divergence.